# making one page with wordpress and problems with style pages

Tags: php, wordpress, single-page-application

I'm trying to create my own theme with wordpress and I'd like to concatenate different pages created into one page.

To do so, I've created a page called "Accueil" and a template "One page" that loops into each pages.

It worked well -> all my posts were displayed into the homepage
But I've found out that there were still a problem in redirections since the other pages were also displayed separately (url like: localhost/portfolio/home). To fix it, I've added in functions.php a function to redirect all pages to the homepage, taking into account the name of targeted page to add create the anchor attached to my menu and all works intead of my style designed with elementor that is not at all displayed. How can I do ?

Is there anyone could help me to fix it please or to explain me the right way to create a one page because I'm not very convinced to my method ?

Thank you in advance. Have a good day :)

**functions.php**

```
  function redirect_to_home() {
    global $post;
    if(!is_page('Accueil')) {
      wp_redirect(home_url().'#'.$post->post_title);
      exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');
```

**template-onepage.php**

```
<?php

get_header();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array(54, 83),
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $p) :
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
        echo $content;
    endforeach;
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: please clarify this sentence: `taking into account the name of targeted page to add create the anchor attached to my menu and all works intead of my style designed with elementor that is not at all displayed. How can I do ?`

Comment: The links on my menu return for example "localhost/portfolio/#about", "localhost/portfolio/#projects" and i've created as many pages as i have sections on my menu. To be redirected to the sections i've wrote a function in functions.php but as the page change I think that is why I lost the style created with elementor and I don't know how to do.